# Dynamic cast in Java via Reflection

Tags: java, json, dynamic, reflection, dynamic-cast

Is it possible to cast an Object to a specific data type on runtime?

```
HashMap<String, Object> x = mapper.readValue(row, HashMap.class); // mapper is a OR Mapper and read a JSON Object from file
```

The row contains the data type inside.
E.g.

```
"@class":"java.lang.String"
```

I can ascertain the file type from *Object x* via

```
x.getValue().getClass()
```

What want i do? 
I have a big collection of components, which implements a specific interface. This interface allow to set a value, but the value can be a String, a ArrayList or something else.

Eg.

```
((myInterface)component).setValue((castToSpecificDataType)x.getValue());
```

How can I `castToSpecificDataType` replace with `x.getValue().getClass()`?

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't have a `getValue()` method.

Comment: I iterate over the HashMap into a Map

`for(Map.Entry<String, Object> id : containerForDefaultValues.entrySet()) {
              
                    setValueInComponent(c, id);
 }`

Comment: I don't know what `containerForDefaultValues` is or how it relates to your question. You need to be a lot clearer about what you're asking.

Comment: Ok,
`containerForDefaultValues` is a HashMap with all rows from JSON File.

I have some components, which are extends from Swing Components but with a specific interface. 
I iterate over all components (textfield, combobox, ...) and set the value to the content of JSON File

Comment: Casting is not converting. If the object isn't of `TypeX`, trying to cast it to `TypeX` will just result in a `ClassCastException`. It seems that you'd want something like JAXB. Take a look at the Jackson library to see if it can help you, it should contain plenty of tools to give you ideas.

Comment: Provided you can identify the `Method` in the class of `component` you want to invoke, you can then do `method.invoke(component, x.getValue())`, no casts needed because all the parameters are `Object`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It works now 
`Method method = ((Valueable)c).getClass().getMethod("setValue", Serializable.class);`

`method.invoke(c, id.getValue());`